# Spring Security With Cassandra - TimedOutException

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, cassandra

I'm Trying to authenticate user using spring security with Cassandra database. I'm getting following exception:

```
Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select email, lastlogin, password, usertype from login where email=?]; TimedOutException(); nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: TimedOutException()
```

I tired with increasing Cassandra timeout and all consistency levels. I don't get what is causing this error, same query works well in Cassandra DevCenter.

Here is configuration details:

Used versions:

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.9.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <cassandra-driver-core.version>1.0.5-dse</cassandra-driver-core.version>
    <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>
```

Cassandra Dependancy for pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Cussandra Data Source definition for Spring security:

```
<beans:bean id="cassandraDataSource" class="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDataSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="host" value="${cassandra.contactpoints}"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="port" type="int" value="${cassandra.thriftport}"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="keyspace" value="${cassandra.keyspace}"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="user" value="${cassandra.user}"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="password" value="${cassandra.password}"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="version" value="${cassandra.version}"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="consistency" value="${cassandra.consistency}"></beans:constructor-arg>     
</beans:bean>
```

Cussandra properties:

```
cassandra.contactpoints=127.0.0.1
cassandra.thriftport=9160
cassandra.port=9042
cassandra.keyspace=styling_bee
cassandra.user=cassandra
cassandra.password=cassandra
cassandra.version=2.0.0
cassandra.consistency=ALL
```

Spring Security Configuration:

```
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/showyourcloset**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="email"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <jdbc-user-service 
            data-source-ref="cassandraDataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select email, lastlogin, password, usertype from login where email=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select roleid, email, rolename from user_roles where email=?" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already found the solution, but anyway, you are going the wrong way. Instead you have to implement your own UserDetailsService according to http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html.